# How to use jQuery in WordPress?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I want to add jQuery to my own WordPress plugin but all the stuff who I found in network are not working. Can you please check what's wrong with my code?

/cennik/includes/functions.php

```
function fancybox_init()
{
    wp_register_script('fancybox', plugins_url('/cennik/public/js/cennik.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'));
    wp_enqueue_script('fancybox');
}    

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'fancybox_init');
```

/cennik/public/js/cennik.js

```
$(window).ready(function(){
    alert("asd");
});
```

Thank for help!

Comment: Is your js file loading? Note that wordpress themes typically us jQuery.noConflict which means you can't use global `$`

Answer (score 0):

change

```
$(window).ready(function(){
    alert("asd");
});
```

to

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    alert("asd");
});
```

and see what happens

Comment: Nothing happens. the same like with $

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `$` directly in WordPress as other libraries might also use the `$`. You should not use or call jQuery by using `$` it globally.

That is why **you should explicitly use the jQuery object**. You must do it at the minimum when calling the `ready()` function. This is called the *[no conflict](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/)* way of using jQuery.

You can specify the `$` as a parameter of the function and use it inside the function as you would normally do to call jQuery functions.

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
    // Now, you can use $
    $( '#myId' ).addClass( 'newclass' );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed function to

```
function fancybox_init()
{
    wp_enqueue_script('my-custom-script', plugins_url() .'/cennik/public/js/cennik.js', array('jquery'), null, true);

}    

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'fancybox_init');
```

Now it works, thank for help!